# ANDROID WebView javascript redirect won't work

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I'm trying to create a Android WebView app.
When I press a button in the webview with the following code behind it:

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example.nl";
```

Nothing happens, but in the chrome browser on Android it will work.
I can also confirm that javascript is enabled because I can change the backgrond color by using javascript in the webview.

Answer (score 2):

Override the WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading, like this:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

use this instead:

```
window.open("https://www.example.nl", "_self")
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `document.location` without the `href` property ?

Comment: I found this article. Hope this helps. https://getsatisfaction.com/apperyio/topics/window-location-href-no-longer-working-on-android